# PHP: Does base64_encode protect from mysql injections?

Tags: php, mysql, blob, sanitization

I'm trying to set up a PHP page that will safely accept a file upload (a resume), store it as a mysql blob, and provide a download later. But when I download the PDFs later for viewing, they always seem corrupted and won't open properly.

Thanks to a question by Jgoettsch ([php: reversing mysql_real_escape_string's effects on binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885239/php-reversing-mysql-real-escape-strings-effects-on-binary)), I realized that feeding the file data through mysql_real_escape_string (to prevent injection) might corrupt the file contents, and got the idea to pass the binary through base64_encode() instead, and use base64_decode() before download.

Here's some mockup code demonstrating what I'm doing currently (which is not working):

The upload:

```
<? 
// Get file contents
$cv_pointer = fopen($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$cv_content = fread($cv_pointer, filesize($_FILES['cv']['tmp_name']));
fclose($cv_pointer);

// Insert SQL
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO documents (name, file, size, date_uploaded)
  VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', NOW())",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['cv']['name']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($cv_content),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['cv']['size']));
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

And the download:

```
<? 
if (isset($_GET['view_cv'])) {
  $cv = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsApplicationCv);

  header("Content-length: ".$cv['size']); 
  header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$cv['name']);
  echo $cv['file'];
  exit();
}
?>
```

Here are my questions:

1. If you have a file upload field, is that field vulnerable to sql injection? Or am I worrying unnecessarily? Obviously this file upload task would be much simpler if I could just pass the binary to the blob field without any translations.
2. If I feed the uploaded file contents through base64_encode(), is that tantamount to sanitization? or should I encode it then additionally pass the encoded string through mysql_real_escape_string?
3. This all seems like a lot of effort just to store and fetch a PDF. Is there a simpler solution to this common need, that I haven't stumbled on yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO with prepared queries and placeholders, that should solve both the encoding and injection problem.

Comment: It's safe from injection in the same way that NOT stuffing a fork into an electrical outlet protect you from electrocution. The rule for injection vulnerability: If you're using "outside" data in a query, then you're vulnerable. Doesn't matter where the data comes from, even if it's from YOURSELF. You can easily still inject your own queries.

Comment: @MR. Alien: Care to be more specific about what you're NOing to?

Comment: Storing arbitrary binary data in a database is generally accepted as a Bad Idea. What you should be storing is references to files on disk or a bulk object storage service like Amazon S3. Also please **do not** use `mysql_query` in new code, it's deprecated and being removed from future versions of PHP. Escaping binary data will not damage it if you're doing it correctly.

Comment: @MarcB: Thanks for the metaphor, I'll hold onto that one. I was assuming that #1 was a stupid question, but worth asking anyway.

Comment: @tadman: Thanks for the reminder re: mysql_query. And re: escaping binary data, my understanding is that mysql_real_escape_string, generally accepted as the best way to escape incoming binary data, can corrupt PDFs and possibly other file types. Is this incorrect? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885239/php-reversing-mysql-real-escape-strings-effects-on-binary

Comment: @TopherHunt It is not the best way to escape data, but it's the only way to do it reliably if you're still using the creaky `mysql_query` interface. Escaping is only done so that MySQL interprets your data correctly, and upon retrieval it should be fine. However, if you accidentally *doubly* escape your data it can make a mess of things. I'd really **strongly** advise against putting arbitrary binary files in your database. They do not belong there.

Comment: @tadman: Word to all of that. Thanks for the input. mysql_real_escape_string does seem to be mangling my pdfs (and I'm pretty sure I'm not double escaping), but combined with base64_encode it works fine. Taking your advice to heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q** If you have a file upload field, is that field vulnerable to sql injection?

**A** yes (sort of. It's not the fields on a form that are vulnerable to SQL Injection; the vulnerability is really in the code that handles the values submitted in the request.)

**Q** Or am I worrying unnecessarily?

**A** No. You should ALWAYS be aware of the potential for bad things to happen, and write your code in a way that prevents vulnerabilities from being exposed (and exploited.)

**Q** If I feed the uploaded file contents through base64_encode(), is that tantamount to sanitization?

**A** It's nearly there, as long as your base64_encode guarantees that the returned value will contain only [A-Za-z0-9+./=]. Best practice would be to use bind parameters

**Q** or should I encode it then additionally pass the encoded string through mysql_real_escape_string?

**A** barring the use of prepared statements with bind parameters, then best practice dictates that ALL values (including base64_encoded values) be run through mysql_real_escape_string if they are being included in SQL text to be submitted to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about sanitizing, I'm assuming this is for a public website where strangers will be uploading files. Storing user submitted PDF files is a **very bad** idea. Firstly, how can you be certain the file you're receiving is even a PDF? It's 100% possible for users to CURL a malicious file into your database and have users uknowingly download a virus. PDFs themselves (if I recall correctly) can actually glitch their way into executing viruses in certain Windows operating systems, just like WMV and WMA files can.

If you absolutely need a PDF, then the best option is to instead **create** your own PDF file with sanitized data submitted by a user. You can probably find a tutorial online on how to do this. I personally wouldn't recommend using PDFs in the first place since you can use HTML & CSS to build a resume and print it out perfectly.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The PDFs will be submitted by the public, and for the short term I don't see a way around this. We need to make it easy for prospective interns to apply for positions, and accept their CV in the most standard forms they might have it handy in (.docx, .doc, .pdf). It wouldn't fly with HR to require applicants to copy & paste their CV into CKeditor or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I understand you want to build a web app that's friendly to users, but when dealing with files, it gets pretty hard. I don't see a short term solution other than allowing yourself to be subject to security holes. In general, you wouldn't have to worry about injections from MYSQLi or PDO, but the real issue is users who download the files.

Comment: PDF files are not *generally* vulnerable. I am not aware of any vulnerability that isn't fixed by the latest Adobe Reader updates. It might indeed be worth checking that the file actually *is* a real PDF but there's no need to abandon PDF uploads completely.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm taking all this to heart. It sounds like mysqli is the direction I need to go in, and I'm steering in that direction.